# "Group By" not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle10g, group-by

I have a table called ‘ORDER_DETAILS’

[image]

And a table called PRODUCT_DETAIL
[image]

I want to fetch data like

[image]

> Order_total would be sum of (Quantity*price) -> (2*10)+(2*100)+(4*20)=300

I used following query

```
Select  Order_id, (ROUND(SUM(ql.price * ql.quantity), 2) Order_total
From ORDER_DETAILS o
Inner join PRODUCT_DETAIL p
On o.order_id=p.order_id
Group by Order_id
```

But it is giving error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

what I am doing wrong here. I know it would be pretty simple but cannot figure out the problem.

**EDIT:**

Edited query

```
select o.order_id, round(sum(p.price * p.quantity),2) order_total
from order_details o
inner join product_detail p
on o.order_id = p.order_id
group by o.order_id;
```

Comment: There is a parantheses too much and the aliases used in the select list don't match those used for the tables. And order_id needs to be qualified using the corresponding table alias (which works in 10g due to a bug in the parser but will be rejected in 11 onwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the replaced table names as @a_horse_with_no_name recommends, you have a number of other problems, though oddly none of them will lead to a ORA-00979. Might as well list them, though this isn't intended to be harsh...

- you're using table alias `ql` but that isn't defined;
- you're referring to column `unit_price` when you're said the column is just `price`;
- you're missing a closing `)`, or more sensible you have an *extra* `(` before `ROUND`; (I'm not sure `ROUND` is useful - it won't do much unless your prices are fractions of pence/cents/whatever);
- you have a column called `order_id` in both tables but you aren't specifying which to use in the `select` or the `order by`.

With your new table names this works:

```
select o.order_id, round(sum(p.price * p.quantity),2) order_total
from order_details o
inner join product_detail p
on o.order_id = p.order_id
group by o.order_id;

  ORDER_ID ORDER_TOTAL
---------- -----------
         1         300
```

If the `ROUND` was intended to make it show two decimal places, it won't; you'd need to use `TO_CHAR` instead, maybe:

```
select o.order_id, to_char(sum(p.price * p.quantity), '999G999D99') order_total
...

  ORDER_ID ORDER_TOTAL
---------- -----------
         1      300.00
```

Comment: Please see my edits above. I have edited the query and made changes. It is working fine now